# Add table to existing database IOS sqlite

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite DB in my iOS app. In my screen 1, I was successfully able to create a Database, a table, insert into it and retrieve from it.

However from screen 2 when I am trying to create a table in the same database and insert values, I am unable to.

This is the code which I am using.

```
    -(void) createDB{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                      @"coning.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , NAME TEXT UNIQUE , ADDRESS TEXT UNIQUE, PHONE TEXT UNIQUE)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }



}
- (void)saveData {
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO order (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                               @"name", @"address", @"phone"];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"added");
        } else {
           NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }
}
```

I have been using the same code to add entries in table 1 but when I do the same to create table 2, its says 'Failed to add contact'. Can someone suggest where I might be going wrong?

Also I want to make the PK of table 1 as a FK in table 2.

Comment: check the errormsg: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html

Comment: Check the errormsg ^^^ AND use FMDB https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: What is the message from calling `sqlite3_errmsg()` after the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sqlite3_exec() method instead of sqlite3_step().

sqlite3_exec() will execute whatever the query you have given.

I am sure, It will definitely help you.

```
 -(BOOL)createNewTableInExistingDb
  {

       NSArray *array=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *filePath=[array objectAtIndex:0];

       filePath =[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];

       NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

       BOOL success = NO;
      if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) 
      {
         success =YES;
      }
      if (!success) 
       {
          NSString *path2=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];
          success =[manager copyItemAtPath:path2 toPath:filePath error:nil];
 }
    createStmt = nil;
    NSString *tableName=@"SecondTable";
   if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
     if (createStmt == nil) {

         NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table %@(RegNo integer, name text)",tableName];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &createStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
    return YES;
}
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: This works great to create the table. However I code which I was using earlier as well was creating the second table, but i am unable to insert into the second table.